# Xcode get text of textfield from a different class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am a beginner in terms of xcode and objective-c and I am currently building an app that reads xml Files and compares their values to textfield values.

I have 2 classes. The first one is my View Controller where my textfields are. The second class is where I iterate through my xml files.

I simply want to be able to access the textfield's text my XML iterator class.
It is important that I can save the text that has been entered in the textfield as a variable in my iterator class.

I attempted to do something like this, but it didn't work:

```
ViewController *viewcontroller = [[ViewController alloc]   initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];

viewcontroller.string = self.myTextField.text;
```

Help would be greatly appreciated since I have had trouble with this for a long time now.

Comment: Look into using a Singleton. Many examples can be found by Googling.

Comment: You shoul check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/626898/how-do-i-create-delegates-in-objective-c) question and answers.

Comment: So the second class, that iterates through the XML files, is also derived from `UIViewController`?

Comment: @mohacs I don't think delegation is the right way to implement this — it would most likely work, but much more cleaner approach from code structure point of view would be to stick to MVC pattern. See my answer below for details.

Comment: @RinatKhanov agreed, stand correcting. A singleton class would be better solution then using protocol in this case.

Comment: Did you figure this out? If so, please accept my answer below and close this question as resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Let's return to the basics of MVC pattern (which stands for Model-View-Controller) — your *view controller* talks directly to your *views* and *model* (or any helpers, like XML iterator in our case). So most likely the right approach would be to give your XML iterator text values directly in your ViewController's implementation and update / reset XML iterator every time text field's value changes.

One way to implement this is to have a strong `@property` to your XML iterator in your `ViewController` class (create XML iterator instance once, then assign in to the property and use it later). Another common way is to implement your XML iterator as a singleton class.

It's hard to tell which option is better in your exact case (for example, you can also use protocols or even notifications). However, this general MVC-oriented approach described above works in most basic cases. For more, read about Model-View-Controller pattern — [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Model-View-Controller/Model-View-Controller.html) is the right place to start.

Comment: MVC has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @user523234 it absolutely does, as it outlines how these views and controllers know about and talk with each other